# How to store critical data of Azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure, web-applications

If an Azure web app is restarted or even goes to idle, all it's global variables are wiped out.

It is possible to store the data in a DB or file system, but I feel that this is a bit of an over kill, and that this problem was already solved elegantly.

What is the best practuce to make data persistent between app restarts?

Uploading a new version of the app, would probably require forcing a wile of all the data.

Comment: Store it in a file? :)

Comment: *all it's global variables are wiped out* -> if you mean that those in memory then yeah, these get wiped of course. And apart from persisting them somewhere (redis cache, db, file whatever) there is no way to keep the values upon restart.

Comment: @Peter Is there an Azure best practice way for making part of the memory persistent?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. It is too dependant on the type of data to determine a single solution for all possible scenario's

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to persist key-value data e.g. user profile, user authentication claims etc. which you want to persist across machine restarts then azure redis is the best solution. This is an in memory (on redis server) data storage solution which would be very performant. This is also a fully managed(resilient, scalable) solution from Microsoft.

Otherwise for  storing business data you have several options you might want to evaluate like azure SQL, my SQL, cosmos db etc  based on your usage , volume and existing technology ecosystem.